# How to use layoutPriority on 1 component while using maxWidth / minWidth on deprioritized component

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text, swiftui-layout

I am trying to create a UI component where we have a horizontal cell containing a title / subtitle on the leading side.

Then at the trailing end of the component, there's an optional text (*actionText*), like so:

[image]

**This is what I want to accomplish:**

1. *Prioritizing* the spacing of the title and subtitle - so if the either are long, we want to make the actionText use the `minWidth` and extend vertically (3 lines max). This part *looks* like it's working with the image above.
2. If the title and subtitle are short and we have a longer actionText, it can expand to the `maxWidth`. This part does not work.

**This is what is happening:**

1. The actionText is only taking up the `minWidth` even when the title / subtitle are short.
2. I tried to wrap the actionText in its own `VStack` and applied the frame parameters on the stack. But I saw the same result.
3. I tried using `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)` on the actionText but this doesn't allow the actionText to vertically expand.

[image: Since the title / subtitle are short, the actionText should use the maxWidth]

**The code I currently have:**

```
public var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 8) {
        VStack {
            if let title, !title.isEmpty {
                Text(title)
            }
            if let subtitle, !subtitle.isEmpty {
                Text(subtitle)
            }
        }
        .layoutPriority(1)


    if let actionText, !actionText.isEmpty {
        Text(actionText)
            .textStyle(.body)
            .frame(minWidth: 45, maxWidth: 96, alignment: .trailing)
            .lineLimit(3)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? I have tried so any random things to get this to work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this was me being an idiot and not realizing             .textStyle(.body) had it's own frame set for the text.